# How to use third party lib in embedded dynamic framework for iOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Now I have a project, like testApp, using some third party lib like alamofire and some others libs in objective-c.

Now I want to add a today widget. According to some tutorial, I created a new target "testAppKit" as a shared dynamic framework, and target "testAppWidget" as today extension. The common code will be in testAppKit for reuse.

Now I need to use third party libs in testAppKit. And added lib and header in build phases of testAppKit. Then I add `#import <theLib/TheHeader.h>` in testAppKit.h. But there is an error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'testAppKit'
```

So, I want to know how to use third party libs (maybe in Swift or Objective-C) in this kind of embedded dynamic framework.

Answer (score 7):

I use Dropbox Datastore API in my app and I finally made it working for embedded Cocoa Touch framework to share code for Containing App and Today Extension.

I figured out that in my Swift file in the embedded framework I can import any 3rd party framework I had in the Project (i.e. Farbic.framework, Crashlytics etc.) but not Dropbox.

What was the difference? The "Modules" folder! Dropbox.framework doesn't provide module map file. So I created it based on what I found in Fabric.framework:

1. Go to the Dropbox.framework folder in your project direcotry.
2. Create new folder "Modules" and go inside
3. Create a file called: "module.modulemap"

The content of the file:

```
framework module Dropbox {
    umbrella header "Dropbox.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

After doing that I needed to add import path.

1. Go to your Project file
2. Select your embedded framework target
3. Go to the "Build Settings" and find "Swift Compiler - Search Paths"
4. Add path to your Dropbox.framerowk and set "recursive" option.

I wanted to put a screenshot here but I can't do that yet - because of my "reputation" ;)

Now I'm able to do "import Dropbox" in my swift files :)

Hope this can help you :)